# Share implementation files among Chrome (packaged) Apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I have several Chrome Apps that share various assets (CSS, JavaScript, and the like), but it seems that all of the constituent files are required to be in the app folder. I don't want to put these files on a server, because I want the app to be entirely self-contained. I tried OS X aliases, but the Chrome system didn't recognize them in <script> elements.

Obviously, I don't want to maintain multiple copies of these files, as some of them change often during development.

Any ideas short of writing a preprocessor that's run every time a file changes? It would use a file called something like files.json that lists the assets not already in the folder or one of its subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

We currently have experimental support for "shared modules", where one extension or app can depend on a set of others. The dependencies just provide files which can be loaded in the apps/extensions that depend upon them ; they cannot have any permissions or features (like a background page) of their own. At install time for an app/extension that depends on shared modules, we will automatically download and install any missing dependencies from the chrome webstore, as well as remove them later if you uninstall all apps/extensions that depend on them.

Right now the feature is only available in the dev channel of chrome, but we intend to fully support it when we've had a chance to get developer feedback. If you want to try it out, grab a copy of the [chrome dev channel (or canary)](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

In the manifest.json for an extension that is just a bundle of files you want to share:

```
{
  ...

  "export": {
    "resources": [ "foo.js", "bar.js" ]
  },

  ...
}
```

In the manifest.json for an extension/app that wants to depend on the above:

```
{
  ...

  "import": [{"id": "<id of dependency goes here>"}],

  ...
}
```

See the test data files in this codereview for more examples:

https://codereview.chromium.org/13971005

(Sorry we don't have good documentation for this yet ; we will eventually)

Give it a try and send some feedback to extensions-dev@chromium.org or apps-dev@chromium.org.

Comment: I forgot to mention that at install time for an app/extension that depends on shared modules, we will automatically download and install any missing dependencies from the chrome webstore, as well as remove them later if you uninstall all apps/extensions that depend on them.

Answer (score 1):

Normally such are done via package manager. You can use [bower](http://bower.io/) to add some local git dependency. Or if you simply want to copy files to your folder every time the target files have changed you can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task runner with [Watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) task.

Answer (score 0):

When I said "writing a preprocessor" I overstated what would need to be done. jusio's solution I guess works, but I did something even simpler, with this script run from inside BBEdit:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /Users/marc/Documents/Dropbox/dev/chrome
rsync -vrt lib NoteTree
open '/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Default nnlinebecgjceggljgcnfploamgnjjhl.app'
```

This copies the changed files and then invokes the Chrome App. If it's already running, which it usually is during development, I just right-click and choose Reload App. It's a very quick edit-and-test cycle.

(Explanation: /Users/marc/Documents/Dropbox/dev/chrome is the parent folder for my development, subfolder lib contains the common files, and NoteTree is the app I'm currently working on.)

Comment: This is roughly what we do on the Chrome Apps team. Most of our apps are small because our main goal is developing the apps platform, not the apps themselves. It's likely we'd come up with something more powerful if we were working on a suite of large related apps.